# Получаю ошибку Dispatcher() takes no arguments

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pycharm

```
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
import random

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
MSG = '{}'
TOKEN = '11111111111111111111111111111'

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
line = open('phrase2.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8").readlines()


@dp.message_handler(command=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_full_name = message.from_user.full_name
    logging.info(f'{user_id=} {user_full_name=} {time.asctime()}')
    turn_on_random = random.choice(line)
    await message.reply(f'{turn_on_random}')
    dtn = datetime.datetime.now()
    botlogfile = open('TestBot.log', 'a', encoding="utf8")
    print(dtn.strftime(f"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"), f'Пользователь ' + message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.id,
          f'написал сообщение: ' + message.text, file=botlogfile)
    botlogfile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ivan\PycharmProjects\Motion\main.py", line 22, in 
dp = Dispatcher(bot=Bot)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Dispatcher() takes no arguments

Что пробовал: **import Dispatcher** переделал в **from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher** - не помогло

Раньше код работал, но после переустановки винды всё пришлось снести и поставить заново, теперь не работает, выходит эта ошибка. Может кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой? В интернете ничего толкового не обнаружил...
ПС: Последняя версия питона, последняя версия аиограма, все библиотеки обновил до последних версий, работаю в пайшарме.

Comment: «последняя версия аиограма» — вот в этом и ошибка

Comment: пробовал откатить до более старых, но тогда пишет, что message_handler не работает в ней, какая версия оптимальная не подскажете?

Comment: Очевидно, та, под которую был написан этот код

Answer (score 0):

Вместо вашего

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
```

примените

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher
```

(т. е. **без** `.dispatcher`)

Comment: изначально так и делал, отсюда и начались приключения, одно из решений в интернете было как раз сделать с .dispatcher, но тоже не сработало

Answer (score 0):

Итого помог откат питона до версии 3.10 и аиограм версии 2.25.1, может кому то будет полезным. Всем спасибо!